# Custom month and day of week names for NSDateFormatter

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I need to set my own custom month and DOW names for `NSDateFormatter` in order to parse `NSDate` to `NSString`. Is it possible to set array with custom names to the date formatter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the docs for `NSDateFormatter`. Use the `setMonthSymbols:` or `setShortMonthSymbols:` methods (and other similar methods as needed).

This will work for converting an `NSDate` to an `NSString` giving you whatever custom month names and day-of-week names you want in the result.